# How do I inspect the working directory structure of a GoCD job run?

Tags: go-cd

I've got a job that's failing and I think the problem is that I've misunderstood what the layout of the directory structure for the running job.

How can I see what's actually on disk so I can diagnose what's happening?
Can I do it from the GoCD UI, or am I going to have to connect to the agent box and look at things that way?

In Jenkins, I'd just use the "workspace" link to eyeball the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comprehensive way to inspect the structure is to define an "artifact" of `*` - this declares the entire pipeline's working directory as an artifact, then you can inspect it in the UI.

This is probably a very bad plan, because it's going to use up tons of disk space and it takes a long time to create the artifact so it slows down your pipeline a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I'm adding directorying listing commands to the jobs themselves, then inspect the out in the logs.